# Does Facebook send notifications to my web page by the fb app?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have searched on Google and Fb's documentation about this but didn't find anything.

I've already shared content of my page on Facebook with the Share button provided by FB's api and also made an app on Facebook.

**Now I want to receive notifications in my page when someone comments the publication or likes it.**
I know that I can consult the posts/comments/likes if the user gives me the permissions, but I don't want to do this every 5 minutes. **I want that facebook notifies me like a push notification.**

How can I do that if it's possible?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After the user shared something on his wall, there is no way for you to get notified about comments/likes on that wall post, unless you authorize the user with `user_status` or `read_stream`.

That being said, there is the Realtime API with the feed and statuses fields to subscribe to: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/real-time-updates/

That´s probably the best option, although you must authorize the user with the correct permissions too.